# How do I return 0 if random number will be negative?

Tags: java, random

The num1, num2, are bounds of the random number, but I want the result to be 0 if num1 is greater than num2.

```
int num1 = 5
int num2 = 1
int num3 = 10
Random rand = new Random();
    double num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num3; i++) {
        int randNum = rand.nextInt((num2 - num1) + 1) + num1;
        num = num + randNum;
    // Adds the random number generated to num until it reaches the
    // max amount of numbers generated.
    }

    num = num / num3;
    if (num3 < 1 || num2 < num1){ 
        return 0;
    } else {
        return num;
    }
```

I thought the last if statement would work, but it keeps giving me an error that says the random number cannot be negative.

If the solution could be a little simple as I am only just starting on Java

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: if u want a negative random number, then select a min value for it lets say -50, what ever result u get from nextInt function just add this -ve number to it,

Answer (score 3):

Because (according to [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29))

```
public int nextInt(int n)
```

> Parameters: n - the bound on the random number to be returned. Must be
>   **positive**. Returns: the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int
>   value between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive) from this random number
>   generator's sequence Throws: **IllegalArgumentException** - if n is not
>   positive

Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

So you need to check first that `(num2 - num1) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it by doing the num1 to num2 comparison first, and not messing around with any math if num1 is greater.

move this to the top:

```
if (num3 < 1 || num2 < num1){ 
    return 0;
```

Looking at your code again it appears as num3 increases, your result approaches (num2-num1)/2.  Just wondering what your are doing here?

Comment: It's just a method that finds the average number of random numbers between a specified bound.  The num3 is what tells you how many random numbers you are going to have. So yes that is correct, it should converge to (num2-num1)/2

Comment: And also, thanks this did work, I did something like this, but it was in the for loop, not before the loop

Comment: I originally posted something like that, but felt it wasted CPU so i edited it out.  int randNum = (num1 > num2) ? 0 : rand.nextInt((num2 - num1) + 1) + num1;

Answer (score -1):

You are not using num1 and num2 as bounds. If should be be

```
randNum = rand.nextInt(num1, num2);
```

also your conditional

```
if(num1 > num2)
```

should be first in your method.

Comment: rand.nextInt(num1, num2) is not a method on Random.